# Why does my routing not work in Angular JS for URL?

Tags: angularjs

I use next configuration for routing:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/appointments', {
                        controller: 'AppointmentController'
                    })
    }])
```

And Controller:

```
.controller('AppointmentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
     alert('Test')
}]);
```

Url is looks like as: `http://blogapp.com/appointments`

So, I have not error on page, but `alert()` does not work when I enter URL

Comment: Try using `http://blogapp.com/appointments` (with an "s" at the end)

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. I have URL with `s`

Comment: Can not because I have page in PHP on /appointments

Answer (score 0):

Try going to

```
http://blogapp.com/#/appointments
```

The hash would be included by default for Angular.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur commented, you would need to go to `http://blogapp.com/#/appointments`

To stop this and remove the #, replace your config with:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/appointments', {
                        controller: 'AppointmentController'
                    })

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }])
```

Comment: I do like as you offer, then other URL from PHP will not work